# fopen() corrupts the path argument

Tags: c

I'm experiencing a strange bug when passing a variable to `fopen()` as opposed to a string literal. Here's the offending piece of code:

```
FILE *rc;
...
rc = fopen ( path, "a" );
```

`path` is defined like this:

```
char path [ sizeof ( getenv ("HOME") ) + 8]; /* 8 is the length of "/.bashrc" and "/.tcshrc" which are the .*rc files with the longest names */
strcpy ( path, getenv ("HOME") );
...
if ( <check for shell> ) {
    strcat ( path, "/.*rc" );
}
```

Here's the output prior to calling `fopen()`:

```
${HOME}/.*rc (for example /home/user/.bashrc)
```

And after:

```
"$HOME" + square + \t + "rc"
```

... use your imagination.

Why is `fopen()` altering `path`? Am I doing something wrong or is this a known bug (I did not find anything online and the man pages don't mention it?)

Comment: I haven't looked through the rest carefully enough to be sure, but at first glance, `sizeof(getenv("HOME"))` looks like a problem. Looks like you really want `strlen`, not `sizeof` here.

Comment: The way you're creating `path` is probably invoking undefined behavior in some way, leading to it to get corrupted in `fopen`.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use `strlen(getenv("HOME"))`, not `sizeof(getenv("HOME"))`. `getenv` returns a pointer, not an array (it's not possible to return an array in C), so `sizeof` is returning the size of a pointer, which is probably just `4`.

Also, you need to allow space for the trailing `0` byte that all strings have. If you'll be appending 8-character strings like `"/.bashrc"`, you need to add `9` to the length of the home directory when you allocate `path`. So it should be:

```
char path [ strlen ( getenv ("HOME") ) + 9];
```

Comment: `strcat` will write the null byte, but it's still up to you to leave enough room for it in the `path` array.